# PHP library to get center of the polygon center

Tags: postgis, geojson, php, geophp

I have the folloging example GeoJSON data stored in a PostgreSQL PostGIS database:

```
{"geoJSON":{"type":"Feature","properties":[],"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[30.502390312011734,50.4947950787348],[30.504106925781265,50.43731985018662],[30.577234672363296,50.469234876725125],[30.502390312011734,50.4947950787348]]]}}}
```

I need some PHP library to calculate polygon center using coordinates array on back-end side.
What existing libraries can do it?

Comment: since you mention postgis, have a look at [`st_centroid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GeoPHP](https://geophp.net/) is a popular extension for geospatial manipulation and had a *centroid* method for what you want to do.